# QML Keys.onPressed issue

Tags: qml

I have a problem : when I change the property of an Item in Keys.onPressed, the property isn't updated on the graphic side, here is my code:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect

    focus:true
    visible: true
    width: 1440
    height: 900


    Keys.onPressed: {


        if (event.key == 65){
            rect.color="#88ff88"
            console.log("key pressed")
        }


    }



}
```

I get the log on the console, but the color of the rectangle stays white. Do you know why?

Comment: I can't see any problems. It works for me. Have you tested the code you posted, if it really includes your problem?

Comment: yes, I've tested it and I really can't understand why it doesn't work. Maybe it's Qt creator? Is there a thing like a cache which can cause the problem in QtCreator?

Comment: Ok, I've restarted the the software and it works, sorry to have taken some of your time for nothing, at least you made me realize that it was something outside the code!